# Dictionary key value could not fetch python

Tags: python, dictionary

I try to write down a code to find out the average temperature of the weekend's in python.

```
toronto_weather = {
    "Monday": 10,
    "Tuesday" : 12,
    "Wednesday" : 15,
    "Thursday" : 10,
    "Friday" : 9,
    "Saturday" : 6,
    "Sunday" : 6
    }

def weekend_avg_c(toronto_weather):

    #A weekend is Saturday and Sunday. You need to find the sum of those two temps 
    total_degrees = 0
    for days in toronto_weather.values():
      if toronto_weather.get('key')=='Saturday' or toronto_weather.get('key')=='Sunday':
        total_degrees = total_degrees + days

    
    #total_degrees has the sum of the weekend temps.
    return (total_degrees/2)
print(weekend_avg_c(toronto_weather))
```

I got this `0.0` as the answer.

How do I fix this code?

Comment: What *exactly* do you think `toronto_weather.get('key')` is doing?

Comment: Also, if you already know the keys you are interested in, why the loop?

Comment: Have you thought about what `toronto_weather['Saturday']` might give you?

Comment: Show us *exactly* what you don't understand from when you traced the intermediate expressions in this code.  We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.  All you've done so far is to set a variable to 0, execute some intermediate code, and then wonder why the variable hasn't changed.  Before posting here, you need to investigate how your code works.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp I have to use for loop to do it. Therefore, I can not access the keys directly.

Comment: @Saswati Can you use something like `for day, value in toronto_weather.items():`? Then you just need to check whether the day is Saturday or Sunday, and if so, include the value in your total. You may want to read more about how to use `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()`, `dict.items()` and `dict.get()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the values directly with your keys

```
return (toronto_weather['Saturday'] + toronto_weather['Sunday'])/2
```

EDIT:

If you need to use a loop, you are not iterating over the days in your original code, just the values, you need to iterate over the keys:

You need to change `toronto_weather.values()` into `toronto_weather.keys()`

```py
def weekend_avg_c(toronto_weather):
    #A weekend is Saturday and Sunday. You need to find the sum of those two temps 
    total_degrees = 0
    for days in toronto_weather.keys():
      if days=='Saturday' or days=='Sunday':
        total_degrees = total_degrees + toronto_weather[days]
    #total_degrees has the sum of the weekend temps.
    return (total_degrees/2)
```

Comment: Yeah I can do that. But I was told to do it using for loop.